# glDrawElements not drawing anything

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am using c/c++ (NDK) for android to program in opengl es 2.0. I am using the GLM library !

so far I can draw a white triangle on a black background using glDrawArrays but when I try to draw the same triangle using glDrawElements it does not draws anything.

Relevant code:

```
float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
           0,  5, 5, // top
          -5, 0, 5, // bottom left
           5, 0, 5  // bottom right
  };

 float color[] = { 1,1,1, 1.0f };
 GLuint drawOrder[]={0,1,2};

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(program);

int positionHandle=glGetAttribLocation(program,"vPosition");

int matrixHandle = glGetUniformLocation(program, "uMVPMatrix");

glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixHandle,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(mvpMatrix));

glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,triangleCoords);

int colorHandle =glGetUniformLocation(program, "vColor");

glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 1, color);

//glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); <== This works

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,drawOrder); <== This does not works

glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

 //swapbuffers and stuff
```

Shaders are extremely basic

```
std::string vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition; "
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;  "
        "void main() {"
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix*vPosition;"
        "}";

    std::string fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;"
        "uniform vec4 vColor;"
        "void main() {"
        "  gl_FragColor = vColor;"
        "}";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGLES does not guarantee support for GL_UNSIGNED_INT for indices. Use GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT:

```
GLushort drawOrder[]={0,1,2};
```

...

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,3,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,drawOrder);
```

Comment: Well done sir , that did the trick. However it limits the max no of indices to 65k which would be killer for phone GPUs but still it leaves ES at an disadvantage compared to desktop versions. Just for curiosity , is there a workaround this to index more than 65k ?

Comment: You just have to split large meshes into smaller ones that are under the limit and use different arrays for each. The limit doesn't affect the total number of triangles that can be rendered per frame.